# How to extract a value from a JSON file containing an encoded JSON object

Tags: json, aws, jq

The command `aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket bucketname`
outputs:

```
{
    "Policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Id\":\"S3SecureTransportPolicy\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"ForceSSLOnlyAccess\",\"Effect\":\"Deny\",\"Principal\":{\"AWS\":\"*\"},\"Action\":\"s3:*\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::amn/*\",\"Condition\":{\"Bool\":{\"aws:SecureTransport\":\"false\"}}},{\"Sid\":\"AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20150319\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":\"cloudtrail.amazonaws.com\"},\"Action\":\"s3:GetBucketAcl\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::amn\"},{\"Sid\":\"AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":\"cloudtrail.amazonaws.com\"},\"Action\":\"s3:PutObject\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::amn/AWSLogs/405042254276/*\",\"Condition\":{\"StringEquals\":{\"s3:x-amz-acl\":\"bucket-owner-full-control\"}}}]}"
}
```

I need to grep (i.e., extract) the value associated with the key `aws:SecureTransport` from this JSON (it would be `false`, in this case) and the value associated with the key `Effect`.

I've tried

```
aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket amn |
    grep -Po '"Bool": *\K"[^"]*"'
```

and

```
aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket amn |
    sed 's/.*\(aws:SecureTransport\)[^:]*:"\([0-9]*\)"'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

The JSON document that you get from your command seems to contain another encoded JSON document. It's from this encoded document you appear to want to get the data.

To get at the internal document, we may use `jq`:

```
aws ... |
jq -r '.Policy'
```

To get the value of the `Effect` key from the bit that contains that `aws:SecureTransport` key from this, we need to parse the document again:

```
aws ... |
jq -r '.Policy' |
jq -r '.Statement[] | select(.Condition.Bool."aws:SecureTransport").Effect'
```

The last `jq` call goes through all the elements of the `Statement` array, looking for one that has a key called `.Condition.Bool."aws:SecureTransport"`.  It then gets the value of the `Effect` key associated with that `Statement` element.

Running this on your data outputs the value `Deny`.

If you want the value of that `.Condition.Bool."aws:SecureTransport"` key (`false` in your document), use `.Condition.Bool."aws:SecureTransport"` in place of `.Effect` above.

Alternatively, use the `fromjson` instruction in `jq` instead of a second `jq` invocation:

```
aws ... |
jq -r '.Policy | fromjson | .Statement[] | select(.Condition.Bool."aws:SecureTransport").Effect'
```

Here, `fromjson` decodes the encoded JSON document and passes it to the later stages of processing.

---

Just for reference, the internal encoded JSON document looks like this (`aws ... | jq -r '.Policy | fromjson'`):

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3SecureTransportPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ForceSSLOnlyAccess",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::amn/*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20150319",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::amn"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::amn/AWSLogs/405042254276/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, do not do this! Use `jq` as described in [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613337/22222). That is a far more robust solution than fiddling around with regular expressions. That said, here's one way to do it with `grep`:

```
aws ... | grep -oP 'aws:SecureTransport.":."\K.+?(?=\\")'
```

That will look for `aws:SecureTransport`, then any character (`.`; this is just simpler than writing `\\` to escape the slash), then a `"`. The `\K` will discard anything matched up to this point (so the part matching `aws:SecureTransport.":."`). Then, look for the shortest string (`.+?`) that is followed by `\"` (`(?=\\")`).

Running this on a file containing your example output gives:

```
$ grep -oP 'aws:SecureTransport.":."\K.+?(?=\\")' file
false
```

Comment: that should be prefered over @kusalananda's answer, it looks way more cryptic, and is more error prone, so it is closer to unix philosophy.

Comment: @Archemar using regex instead of proper JSON parsing is going to be far more error prone than an actual JSON parser that was *designed* for this.